# Losing zone.js properties after using await command

Tags: node.js, adonis.js, zone.js

I'm using zone.js inside my AdonisJs project to create execution context. I have a piece of middleware that creates a zone as follows:

```
async handle ({ request, response }, next) {
    let token = jwtDecode( request.header('Authorization') )

    // Create a zone so we have execution context throughout the flow
    return Zone.current.fork({

        name: Math.random(),
        properties: {
            username: token.username,
            user_id: token.sub
        }
    }).run( async () => {

        // call next to advance the request
        await next()
    })
}
```

Inside my controller I can access my zone properties with

```
let username = Zone.current.get('username')
```

However, the moment I use the `await` command I lose access to the zone properties, all are undefined. For example:

WORKS

```
let username = Zone.current.get('username') // ALL OK
let order = await Order.find(params.id);
```

NOT WORK

```
let order = await Order.find(params.id);
let username = Zone.current.get('username') // UNDEFINED
```

Can anybody please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, currently `zone.js` not support native `async/await`.